# BeautifulSoup: No connection adapters were found error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-imaging-library

My goal is to search google for a specified string and save the image from the found url. I have been following online tutorials but keep getting the same InvalidSchema error and do not know why.

```py
from PIL import Image
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

text= "animal+crossing"

html_page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.text, 'html.parser')
image = soup.find('img')
img_url = image['src']

img = Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream = True).raw)
img.save('image.jpg')
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, however, please take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/ashokpant/730df861116b17f3c5d4dfef49e0b6ca) program made by ashokpant. This crawler might better suit what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The image url that you're grabbing in this step: `img_url = image['src']` is not actually a valid url.  Here's the value I see for `img_url` when I run your code:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
```

Comment: yes you're right, I see now that it's not a valid URL. However I am unsure how to fix this.

Comment: It's likely not possible to grab a valid url from Google images. Google doesn't want individual users scraping their pages, and they use special url's in order to prevent it

Comment: is there another web-page then that you would suggest I use to scrape images from? It is for a personal project and I just want to grab images of video games

Comment: @uwu The vast majority of sites will allow you to scrape them. It's just big sites like Google with lots and lots of security that try to prevent that sort of thing.  I'd recommend trying to scrape [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Crossing); that should be more straightforward